# Create new node module object from kotlin

Tags: javascript, node.js, kotlin

I'm trying to write a small node.js application in Kotlin to test and play with the javascript interop. From an external node module 'foo' which exposes a prototype 'Bar', I am trying to create a new instance of 'Bar'.

In Javascript I would simply write something like

```
var foo = require('foo')
var bar = new foo.Bar()
```

In Kotlin, I defined an external function 'require' and load the module which works as expected:

```
external fun require(module: String): dynamic
...
val foo = require("foo")
//Somehow create a new Bar
```

Now I would like to create a new instance of Bar. So far I've tried:

- Calling `val bar = foo.Bar()`. This is interpreted as function and thus doesn't work.
- Defining an external class Bar and creating a new object `val bar = Bar()`

The only workaround I could find is to instantiate the object via native javascript code: `val bar = js("new foo.Bar()")`. This works, but has a few disadvantages:

- it is not typesafe (which is part of the beauty of using kotlin)
- it has an implicit dependency on the variable foo which is not checked at compile time
- The module exposes many such objects with different sets of constructor parameters, which would result in a lot of native code as above, which I would like to avoid

Is there any way to achieve this, prefearably in pure kotlin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have to define `Bar` as an external class from module `foo`:

```
@JsModule("foo")
external class Bar {
   ...
}
```

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-modules.html and https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-interop.html